# Notice: Undefined variable: grandTotal in PHP 7.1

Tags: php

I am getting undefined variable as I sum up the total in for loop.
I declare using empty string but it is giving me non-numeric value error 
and I don't know why I am getting this error.

```
$detail= array(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [item] => 8
            [plant] => 4
            [uom] => 1
            [t_load] => 1
            [rate] => 5
            [quantity] => 289
            [total] => 6310
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 5
            [item] => 13
            [plant] => 6
            [uom] => 1
            [t_load] => 1
            [rate] => 16
            [quantity] => 300
            [total] => 6310
        )
)
<?php foreach($detail as $details):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $details['plant']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['item']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['t_load']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['quantity']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['rate']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['total']; ?></td>
</tr><?php

     $grandTotal += $details['total'];
endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define `$grandTotal` outside of your loop like this.

```
<?php 
$grandTotal = 0;
foreach($detail as $details):?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $details['plant']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['item']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['t_load']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['quantity']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['rate']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $details['total']; ?></td>
</tr><?php

     $grandTotal += $details['total'];
endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Define at the top

```
  <?php 
 $grandTotal  = 0;
 foreach($detail as $details):?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $details['plant']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $details['item']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $details['t_load']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $details['quantity']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $details['rate']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $details['total']; ?></td>
</tr><?php

    $grandTotal += $details['total'];
 endforeach; 
?>
```